# Why there is a issue editing PLIST file only on iPhone 4?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, plist

I'm actually coding and testing an app on a iPhone 4s, and my PLIST editor works like a charm.
Then I wanted to try it on an iPhone 4, and I constated that the PLIST file is never edited.
Here my code for writing my array into a file :

```
- (BOOL)writeArrayToPlist:(NSArray*)plistArray
{
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"DataList" ofType:@"plist"];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:filePath error:NULL];

    return [plistArray writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

}
```

Am i missing something ? thanks !

Comment: That code won't work on any real device. An app's bundle is read-only on a real iOS device.

Comment: it's working fine on my 4s :s

Comment: Is it jailbroken? Such code normally won't work.

Comment: It's a bad idea to use a jailbroken device for development testing if your goal is to put the app on the App Store.

Comment: @rmaddy would you please put these comments into an answer so this question is properly marked as 'answered'

Comment: @Daij-Djan I was kidding. That's why I put the smiley. It's OK.